# Commenting on another Facebook page as my page, why is the comment only visible to me?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Whenever I comment on another Facebook page as my page, it seems that the comment is only visible to me and people that already like my page. Is this really true? Any way to surpass this, or is this an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sure that what you are saying is true. (Can one of your friends confirm it?)

Visibility is open to all.

[image: Proof]

Comment: I am confident that it is true, but I know why now. The comments were hidden by the owner of the page, but thank you for the help.